# Null pointer exception while jdbctemplate

Tags: spring, spring-jdbc

Getting NullPointerException with a spring jdbc example

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.net.technicalkeeda.dao.PersonDaoImpl.findTotalCustomer(PersonDaoImpl.java:46)
```

This is the method where i get the jdbcTemplate as NULL, when i call findTotalCustomer method from controller. But at server startup it assigns values to datasource and jdbctemplate. So can you please help me why there is a NULL value.

This is my controller class from i am accessing the dao method

```
public class HelloController implements Controller {

    public ModelAndView handleRequest(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

        ApplicationContext ctx = new FileSystemXmlApplicationContext("classpath*:/WEB-INF/springtutorial-servlet.xml");

        if (ctx != null) {
            personDao = (PersonDaoImpl)ctx.getBean("personDao");
        }


        personDao.findTotalCustomer();

        return new ModelAndView("hello.jsp");
    }

}
```

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName"><value>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</value></property>
        <property name="url"><value>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/technicalkeeda</value></property>
        <property name="username"><value>root</value></property>
        <property name="password"><value></value></property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="personDao" class="com.net.technicalkeeda.dao.PersonDaoImpl">
    <property name="dataSource"><ref local="dataSource" /></property>
    </bean>



package com.net.technicalkeeda.dao;

import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.Collection;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.RowMapper;

import com.net.technicalkeeda.bean.Person;

/**
 * @author Yashwant Chavan
 * 
 */
public class PersonDaoImpl {


    private DataSource dataSource;

    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    public void setDataSource(DataSource dataSource) {
        this.dataSource = dataSource;
        this.jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);

        System.out.println("Updated Datasouce---->" + dataSource);
        System.out.println("Updated Jdbctemplate---->" + jdbcTemplate);
    }

    /* Display all persons */
    public Collection<Person> findAll() {
        System.out.println("Calling............." + this.jdbcTemplate);
        return jdbcTemplate.query(
                "select emp_name, emp_salary from trn_employee",
                new PersonMapper());

    }

    public int findTotalCustomer(){

        String sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM trn_employee";
        System.out.println("jdbcTemplate" + jdbcTemplate);
        int total = jdbcTemplate.queryForInt(sql);

        return total;
    }

    private static final class PersonMapper implements RowMapper {

        public Object mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {
            Person person = new Person();
            person.setFirstName(rs.getString("emp_name"));
            return person;
        }
    }

}
```

console log

```
17 Jul, 2012 8:08:52 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader validateJarFile
INFO: validateJarFile(C:\javaworkspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\SpringTutorial\WEB-INF\lib\j2ee.jar) - jar not loaded. See Servlet Spec 2.3, section 9.7.2. Offending class: javax/servlet/Servlet.class
17 Jul, 2012 8:08:52 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'springtutorial'
17 Jul, 2012 8:08:52 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet initServletBean
INFO: FrameworkServlet 'springtutorial': initialization started
17 Jul, 2012 8:08:52 PM org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext prepareRefresh
INFO: Refreshing org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext@7ab2c6a6: display name [WebApplicationContext for namespace 'springtutorial-servlet']; startup date [Tue Jul 17 20:08:52 IST 2012]; root of context hierarchy
17 Jul, 2012 8:08:52 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/springtutorial-servlet.xml]
17 Jul, 2012 8:08:52 PM org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext obtainFreshBeanFactory
INFO: Bean factory for application context [org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext@7ab2c6a6]: org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@2d8e8541
17 Jul, 2012 8:08:52 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory preInstantiateSingletons
INFO: Pre-instantiating singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@2d8e8541: defining beans [dataSource,personDao,helloController,loggerInterceptor,performanceInterceptor,urlMapping]; root of factory hierarchy
17 Jul, 2012 8:08:53 PM org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource setDriverClassName
INFO: Loaded JDBC driver: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
**Updated Datasouce---->org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource@38827968
Updated Jdbctemplate---->org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate@7df0b7d3**
17 Jul, 2012 8:08:53 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet initServletBean
INFO: FrameworkServlet 'springtutorial': initialization completed in 453 ms
17 Jul, 2012 8:08:53 PM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11BaseProtocol start
INFO: Starting Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-8080
17 Jul, 2012 8:08:53 PM org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket init
INFO: JK: ajp13 listening on /0.0.0.0:8009
17 Jul, 2012 8:08:53 PM org.apache.jk.server.JkMain start
INFO: Jk running ID=0 time=0/0  config=null
17 Jul, 2012 8:08:53 PM org.apache.catalina.storeconfig.StoreLoader load
INFO: Find registry server-registry.xml at classpath resource
17 Jul, 2012 8:08:53 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 1749 ms
```

Comment: what about `PersonDaoImpl`? is it singleton?

Comment: @Nandkumar Its not a singleton class, dao implemention class , want to access using jdbc, but getting null dataSource

Comment: @publ1c_stat1c  int total = jdbcTemplate.queryForInt(sql);

Comment: never use the `new` operator to obtain bean spring-managed bean instances and ... what about you spring context configuration btw? are you initializing your dao with a reference to a valid `DataSource`?

Answer (score 2):

My guess is that Spring instantiates its beans and injects the DataSource, but instead of getting the bean from the Spring bean factory, you instantiate one yourself, and thus use another instance, not under Spring's control, and thus not initialized with the DataSource.

You should never do `new SomeSpringBean()`. All the bean references should be injected dependencies or should be obtained by asking a bean to the Spring bean factory.

So if your code does `new PersonDaoImpl()`, something is wrong.

Comment: This is my controller method code where ApplicationContext ctx = new FileSystemXmlApplicationContext("classpath*:/WEB-INF/springtutorial-servlet.xml");
  PersonDaoImpl personDao = new PersonDaoImpl(); 
  if (ctx != null) {
   personDao = (PersonDaoImpl)ctx.getBean("personDao");
  }
  
  
  personDao.findTotalCustomer();

Comment: ApplicationContext ctx = new FileSystemXmlApplicationContext("classpath*:/WEB-INF/springtutorial-servlet.xml");
  PersonDaoImpl personDao = new PersonDaoImpl(); 
  if (ctx != null) {
   personDao = (PersonDaoImpl)ctx.getBean("personDao");
  }
  
  
  personDao.findTotalCustomer();

Answer (score 0):

I would hazard a guess and say you are not getting your bean properly out of your context file. The new operator and spring do not play nice. I assume you know how to get the beans out of the `application-context.xml`, but if not, I'll leave this here anyway.

```
    //simple singleton
    private static void initApplicationContext() {
    if (_applicationContext == null)
        _applicationContext = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("PersistenceHelper-context.xml");
}
//get bean
Datasource dataSource = (DataSource) _applicationContext.getBean("dataSource");
```